# Need to extract portion of XML on link button hyperlink click

Tags: xml, vb.net, xslt, xpath

I am displaying `XML` file content as rows of table using `xslt` and I am displaying it successfully, but I need to extract node of an `XML` file based on row clicked by user now I have to do two thing.

1. I need to display a link button or hyperlink button using `xslt`  with each row so that when user clicks a row I will extract that portion or node from xml for again sending request for further work.
2. I need to extract portion of `xml` using `xpath` based on the row clicked and most important how can I relate each hyperlink or link button with its corresponding row or xml node.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

As your are dealing with XSLT and ASP.NET, you can associate onclick event to the table row itself while creating the HTML itself using XSLT.

Now, you have the tagname with you while parsing xslt, so you can set function like

```
<tr iD="tablerow1" onclick="SetTagName('XmlTagName)"/>
```

Then create the javascript function which sets tagname in hidden field

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function SetTagName(tagname) {
        //Set TagName in Hidden field here 

    }
</script>
```

Now you have tagname in hiddenfield. On server side use GetElementsByTagName function to get portion of the xml.
You can do the same using LinkButton.

Comment: Thx manoj but I dont have much knowledge of java script can you give me example using using c#

Comment: Thats the basic javascript you have to use. Without it currently I don't have any idea how set tagname. So, If you use this javascript it will be easier for you.

Comment: Now, your C# code sample will be something like as under:  


    `XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();  
     xmlDoc.Load("xmlpath");  
     string tag_name = HiddenField1.value;  
     XmlNodeList xNode = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName(tag_name);`

Comment: thx manoj but what if I have to getelement from xml document by the value of an attribute of one of the child nodes of parent node.Manoj Pandey thanks again

Comment: To select element by value of the attribute you can use following code  

`xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//Availability/Hotels/Hotel[@Id='3']/Name")`

    Above code selects Hotel Element with attribute Id having value 3